# Cannot set large balance on impersonated account using hardhat_setBalance

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, hardhat

I cannot set any large integer values on my impersonated accounts.

```
await ethers.provider.send("hardhat_setBalance", [addr, "0x56BC75E2D63100000"]);
```

That hex is 100 ETH.

The error i receive is:

> HardhatError: HH17: The input value cannot be normalized to a BigInt:
> Integer 1e+23 is unsafe. Consider using 1e+23n instead. For more
> details, see
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "testsuite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "hardhat.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
    "ethers": "^5.0.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.17.2"
  }
}
```

I am trying to set this balance because when i try and impersonate a user defined address which has zero balance i get the follow error when performing transactions:

> InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 73778394075873568 and the sender's account only has: 0

I guess the solution is to somehow set a large balance so i can perform transaction or somehow make hardhat unit tests require no balance.

Comment: Can you share your test file, showing how you are using hardhat?